# Load test with JMeter and Selenium in parralel

Tags: java, selenium, jmeter, load-testing

I have JMeter, then I integrated Selenium WebDriver.
I created `jp@gc - WebDriver Sampler`, and the code runs perfect. When I change `Number of Threads (users)` to 10, this open me 10 Fireforx Browser and the idea of load testing is not good, because the last browser (10th) start after few second (20 sec). 
How I can run all this in parallel? 
**I want to simulate 10 users to clicks in the site exactly in same time!** :)

Let's say this is the page, which I want to be opened in same time:

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://jmeter-plugins.org')
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

Thanks

Comment: read this http://blog.wedoqa.com/2013/07/how-to-run-parallel-tests-with-selenium-webdriver-and-testng-2/

Comment: Thanks, it's good tutorial, I will try with JUnit4 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your WebDriver Sampler under the [Synchronizing Timer](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer) and set "Number of Simulated Users to Group By" to 10.

Actually this is not something WebDriver Sampler should be doing. You're supposed to create main load by JMeter [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) samplers and have a separate Thread Group with WebDriver Sampler to measure real-life user experience like scripts execution time, layout, etc.

Comment: Wow, this `Synchronizing Timer` is very good solution. Works perfect. 
Can you please give me more info about your second propose. I have WebDriver script (other) which enter and make good functionality test. Let's say test for entering of User with details. And if 100 peopled enter in the site and enter in same time - this exactly what I want to reproduce :)

Comment: Browsers don't do any magic, they just send HTTP requests (mostly GET and POST) so in fact you can simulate this user details entering by using only JMeter's HTTP Request Samplers

Comment: Ok, sounds great with HTTP Requests, but how can config them, to click the button, put text in some field... For example: I have login form, how to say, login in page with this user and password?

Comment: The easiest way to build a test plan skeleton is recording it using [JMeter's Proxy Server](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) or [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1528451-chrome-extension). The process of "typing" is only on client side, in the majority of cases server doesn't know anything about it unless user clicks "login" button - the click triggers the request which you need to simulate.

Comment: I can't start 'HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder', there is error:
http://s13.postimg.org/ur1zsg8yv/err.jpg

Comment: Update your Java to version 7 or higher